# React Router Dom, useNavigate not redirecting to the right url path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In older React Router Dom versions, I was able to use this code to redirect if a user is logged in:

```
history.push('/login?redirect=shipping')
```

Now in `v6,` I am using the `useNavigate` functions instead of `history.push`, but it's not working as it is taking me to `/login/shipping` instead of `/shipping`. Currently, this is my navigate code:

```
let navigateCart = useNavigate() 
// some code here
navigateCart('/login?redirect=shipping') // the mistake is inside the parenthesis here but I don't know what it is!
```

This is my router config:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Container>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfileScreen />} />
      <Route path="/shipping" element={<ShippingScreen />} />
    </Routes>
  </Container>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Login Screen Function :

```
function LoginScreen() {

    let navigateLog = useNavigate()
    let location = useLocation()

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'
    

    const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)
    const { error, loading, userInfo } = userLogin


    useEffect(() => {
        if (userInfo) {
            navigateLog(redirect)
        }
    }, [navigateLog, userInfo, redirect])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(login(email, password))
    }
```

Comment: Show your router configuration

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ok Done! It is working for other routes though !

Comment: @KonradLinkowski If you need more code let me know please

Comment: @bysEcode you declared `navigate` and then using `navigateCart`, is that normal?

Comment: No sorry it is declared navigateCart for both i will change it

Comment: It seems like you have some login in `LoginScreen` that takes this `queryString` and do something with it. If you want to redirect the user to `/shipping` just use `navigateCart('/shipping')`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski This code is meant to redirect me to login. But if user is already logged in it will automatically redirect me to shipping. In older react router version it used to work with history.push() but now with v6 it is not working and i dont know how to make it work

Comment: You are getting the parameter here `redirect=shipping` inside `LoginScreen` component and making the redirection I assume, if so can you past the code for `LoginScreen`?

Comment: @yousoumar yes you are right i just checked. i will pass the code now hope i can understand it! i am new to react and js in general so if you can help me fix it iw ill appreciate

Comment: Thanks @bysEcode ! I pasted an answer, take a look please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change that `navigateLog(redirect)` line inside the `useEffect` in `LoginScreen` to this one:

```
navigateLog(`/${redirect}`);
```

In your case, it's redirecting to `/login/shipping` instead of `/shipping`, cause it's like you are calling `navigateLog("shipping")`, and without `/` in front, it's used as a relative path. This means it takes into account your current path, which in your case happens to be `/login`.

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]

Comment: Thanks man, this completely works. It seems i was missing the '/' in redirect so it was not reading the path correctly! All the best for you man :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks and same for you :)

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The redirect target path is `"shipping"` instead of `"/shipping"`. In `react-router-dom@6` there are relative paths and absolute paths. The difference is simple, absolute paths start with a leading `"/"` character while relative paths do not. `navigate("shipping")` will append `"shipping"` to the end of the current `pathname` and navigate there.

## Solution

Either prepend the leading `"/"` when navigating:

```
navigate(`/${navigateLog}`, { replace: true });
```

Or include it when you initially navigate:

```
navigateCart('/login?redirect=/shipping');
```

You'll likely also want to use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params) hook to access the `redirect` query parameter instead of relying on it to be at a specific string position.

```
function LoginScreen() {
  const navigateLog = useNavigate();
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  ...

  const redirect = searchParams.get("redirect") || '/';
    
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigateLog(redirect, { redirect: true });
    }
  }, [navigateLog, userInfo, redirect])

  ...
```

Note that in issuing the imperative redirect that I've included an options object to the `navigate` function that specifies `replace: true`, this is to issue a REPLACE action instead of a PUSH action.

Comment: It seems the way i was using it i was missing the '/' backslash in the url it worked fine thanks :) and I tried to use searchParams and it also works. The other guy gave me a good answer too so i marked his question as the answer as i tried it first but this is a perfect answer thanks a lot :)